# c++ is clock_gettime() overflowing?

Tags: c++, time

When using the following example code, the tv_nsec value, I presume is looping round because it's *only* an `long`;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  timespec time1, time2;
  timespec timens = {0};
  timens.tv_sec = 1;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
  nanosleep(&timens, (struct timespec *)NULL);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);

  cout << time1.tv_nsec << " : " << time2.tv_nsec << endl;
  cout << (time2.tv_nsec-time1.tv_nsec) << endl;
  return 0;
}

$ ./microtime 
2754095 : 2766801
12706
```

The difference between the start and end time is 12706ns (12.7us), it didn't take 12us to sleep for 1 second, I'm *reasonably* sure of that! So what has happened here, has tv_nsec looped round? Assuming it's an `singed long` to give a smaller range of positive values (0 to 2147483647) instead of an `unsigned long` (0 to 4294967295), 2147483647 nanoseconds is still just over 2 full seconds!

If I change the code to the following I get a seemingly invalid output still;

```
timens.tv_sec = 0;
timens.tv_nsec = 100000;

$ ./microtime
2743552 : 2754327
10775
```

The sleep duration was set for 100,000ns but according to that output the program has slept for 10,000ns. I know that is a small amount of time but I'm trying to show here that whether it is a long time like 1 second or a short time like 100us, there seems to be no accuracy here, or anywhere in between these values. Am I doing something wrong, have I implemented this incorrectly somehow? Why can't I get the actual duration of the event in between the calls to clock_gettime()?

Many thanks for your time.

**Update**

@Oli;
I can test your suggestion with the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  timespec time1, time2;
  timespec timens = {0};
  timens.tv_sec = 1;
  timens.tv_nsec = 0;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
  nanosleep(&timens, (struct timespec *)NULL);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);

  cout <<time1.tv_sec<<"s:"<<time1.tv_nsec<<"ns : "<<
         time2.tv_sec<<"s:"<<time2.tv_nsec<<"ns"<<endl;
  cout <<(time2.tv_nsec-time1.tv_nsec)<<endl;
  return 0;
}

$ ./microtime
0s:2801478ns : 0s:2813732ns
12254
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to take the `tv_sec` field into account when calculating the time interval.

**UPDATE**

Also, `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` measures CPU time used for this process.  If you yield with a `nanosleep`, this timer won't increment.  Try e.g. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead.

Comment: Ah! So in my first example are you saying that tv_sec will have incremented to 1, and tv_nsec will hold the remainder?

Comment: That makes perfect sense but doesn't seem to work (I have updated the question to show). In both my original tests, and in this new test, you can see that the difference between start and stop time is between 10k and 12k nanoseconds every time, that's such a small window to land in every time for such different tests, that seems so coincidental it more like isn't working correctly.

Comment: Thanks Oli for being so prompt and patient with me. It wasn't the most complext solution but I was failing to see it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

from the manual of nano_sleep:

> An unmasked signal will cause nanosleep() to terminate the sleep early, regardless of the SA_RESTART value on the interrupting signal.

As a result your usage of nanosleep() is simplistic:
It should look like this (though this is not tested just to give you a rough idea).

```
timespec requestedSleep = {0};
requestedSleep.tv_sec = 1;

timespec start = {0};
start = /* current real time */;

while( nanosleep(&requestedSleep, NULL) == -1)
{
    timespec end.t = {0};
    end = /* current real time */;

    updateRequestedSleepTime(requestedSleep, start, end);
    start = end;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Loki for this additional info on nanosleep, I will stuff this into a tester app and have a play. Thank you :D